# Elasticsearch: aggregate over a user-defined set of buckets?

Tags: elasticsearch

Let's say I want to do an aggregation over an index of server logs, and I want separate results for mobile and non-mobile devices. I.e. if the browser type is in  a certain list, then put results in the mobile bucket, else put results in the non-mobile bucket.

I tried something like this: (including a straightforward breakdown over browser type for comparison)

```
{
    "aggs": {
        "group_by_mobility": {
            "filters": {
                "filters": {
                    "mobile": {
                        "terms": {
                            "browser.os.family": [
                                "Android",
                                "iOS",
                                "Windows Phone",
                                "Blackberry OS"
                            ]
                        }
                    },
                    "non-mobile": {
                        "not": {
                            "terms": {
                                "browser.os.family": [
                                    "Android",
                                    "iOS",
                                    "Windows Phone",
                                    "Blackberry OS"
                                ]
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        "group_by_browser": {
            "terms": {
                "field": "browser.os.family",
                "size": 0
            }
        }
    },
    "size": 0
}
```

This runs, but the answers don't look right. I get for the first aggregation:

```
"group_by_mobility" : {
    "buckets" : {
        "mobile" : {
        "doc_count" : 122250
        },
        "non-mobile" : {
            "doc_count" : 711658
        }
    }
}
```

If I add up the numbers in the second aggregation output for the mobile browsers, I get 122404, which is in the same ball park. However, the sum for all other browser types is 304177, which is nowhere near 711658.

Am I taking the wrong approach? Thanks for any hints.

Comment: What is the output for "group by browser"? Does it have any value at "sum_other_doc_count"?

Answer (score 0):

What you want is to run 2 separate aggregations that each have different filter criteria.  Here is the pseudo code:

```
GET index1/type1/_search
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "ag1": {
      "filter": {
        "terms": {
          "authInput.address.address1": [
            "Android",
            "iOS",
            "Windows Phone",
            "Blackberry OS"
          ]
        }
      },
      "aggs": {
        "ag1.terms1": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "authInput.address.address1",
            "size": 10
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "ag2": {
      "filter": {
        "not": {
          "filter": {
            "terms": {
              "authInput.address.address1": [
                "Android",
                "iOS",
                "Windows Phone",
                "Blackberry OS"
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      },
      "aggs": {
        "ag2.terms1": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "authInput.address.address1",
            "size": 10
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
```